# Find the generalized eigenspaces corresponding to the distinct eigenvalues of T

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Define $T$ in $L(\mathbb{C}^2)$ by $T(w,z) = (-z, w)$.
>
> Find the generalized eigenspaces corresponding to the distinct eigenvalues
> of T.

I believe that once I have the eigenvalues, I know how to find the eigenspaces, but I'm not sure I'm looking for the eigenvalues correctly.

I know that if the eigenvalues are $a,b$ corresponding to $(w, 0)$ and $(0, z)$ respectively, then $(ab) = 1$, since $a(w) = -z$ implies $ab(-z) = -z$. But I think my whole approach to this is wrong and that I'm missing some very elementary idea.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You're certainly right that $ab = 1$.  Do you know how to find the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of a linear transformation?  The roots of this polynomial are exactly the transformation's eigenvalues.  First, represent the linear transformation as a matrix with respect to some basis, then compute as in the link.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Ah. So +i, -i. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Your linear transformation can be realized as the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$